# Update an array value in nested document in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql

`Given the following document inside a collection card: I have to update the whole data value for a particular id in staticCard

---

---

`

```
{
  "staticCards": [
    {
         id:123, 
         search:"",
         data:[]

    },
    {
         id:456,
         search:"",
         data:[]
    },
],
    "dynamicCards":[
      {
         id:789,
         search:"",
         data:[]
      },
      {
         id:127,
         search:"",
         data:[]
      },
      {}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the index of the array element, which isn't straightforward if you want to match one of the object attributes instead of the whole object. POSITION() is not an option in this case, but you can solve it with a subquery. Then you can use [REPLACE_NTH()](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-array.html#replace_nth) to set a new value. Finally, you need to update the respective top-level attribute.

```
LET pos = FIRST(FOR i IN 0..LENGTH(doc.dynamicCards)-1
  FILTER doc.dynamicCards[i].id == 127
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN i
)
LET new = REPLACE_NTH(doc.dynamicCards, pos, { id: 128, search: "", data: [] })
UPDATE doc WITH { dynamicCards: new } IN coll
```